# I want to make semi-identical manu like the one on this page - how?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu, navigation

I would like to make a manu similar to the one on [THIS](http://themes.themegoods2.com/keres/) page.

When I hover over HOME , HOME moves to right (how to do this) and the whole sub menu appears - through animation. When I look to Dev Tools I cant work out whether this menu is made in CSS ONLY or with javascript. Could somebody explain briefly how to make such manu for instance if it is jquery or javascript where to find library.

Comment: That obviously uses JavaScript and jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it even using pure CSS:

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; font-family: 'Segoe UI'; -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease; -o-transition: all 0.5s ease; transition: all 0.5s ease;}
label, a {text-decoration: none; cursor: pointer; color: #99f;}
li {padding: 5px;}
#menu {display: none;}
.menu-trigger {position: absolute; border: 1px solid #ccc; display: inline-block; padding: 5px; left: 0;}
.menu-bar {position: absolute; width: 75px; border: 1px solid #ccc; padding: 5px; left: -90px;}
#menu:checked + .menu .menu-trigger {left: -90px;}
#menu:checked + .menu .menu-bar {left: 0;}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="menu" />
<div class="menu">
  <label for="menu" class="menu-trigger">Menu</label>
  <div class="menu-bar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label for="menu">Close</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Fiddle: http://output.jsbin.com/qeyocodepe**

Comment: However in that page http://themes.themegoods2.com/keres/ the page starts with list items equivalent to your "home" "contact" "close" and only then when you click close the checkbox appears. In your example the page starts with checkbox.

Comment: @Piotr The checkbox never appears.

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/7i9t6z2k5/

Comment: The check box is the menu. Can't you do it on your own? This is StackOverflow not SpoonFeedMeOverflow.